# Auto resize parent div

Tags: html, css

Currently I'm working on a project that needs me to have 2 div's side by side. This isn't such of a problem, except I want the parent div to auto resize properly when one of the subdivs becomes larger.. here comes the problem..

When one is larger than the other it pushes the other to the bottom of the parent div.. my question is; how am I able to fix this?

To see my problem in action: http://jsfiddle.net/zygnz/508/

Thanks!

Comment: It seems in your case the use of float will be enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just updated your Fiddle with the solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/zygnz/511/

**CSS**

```
.right, .left {
  float: left;
}
.clear {
  clear: both;
}
.container div {
    display: block;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
  .
  .
  .
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This one worked really well.. but could you maybe explain what happens with the clear: both?

Comment: the clear:both; clears the float, so that the document continues to render normally :)

Answer (score 0):

hey try adding this to your css on the "div.left":

```
float: left;
```

Comment: Could also be written in a comment.

Comment: Almost worked, but now my parent div isn't resizing when left or right gets bigger: http://jsfiddle.net/zygnz/513/